# Get date object of last day for specific year and month, datejs

Tags: javascript, date, datejs

I am new to [DateJs](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs), and the http://www.datejs.com/ is 530 so I can't find documentation for each method.

I need to get the last day of specific year-month. For example :

I need the last fay of July,2015, which should be 31th,July 2015. I tried below script:

```
<script src="<%=application.getContextPath()%>/js/lib/datejs/date-zh-CN.js"></script>


 to=Date.today().set({year:2015,month:6}).final();//which returns Fri Jul 03 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (中国标准时间)
```

or

```
to=Date.today().set({year:2015,month:6}).final().day();//which returns Sat Jul 04 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (中国标准时间)
```

Which are wrong (The day I am ruining the script is at Aug 3rd, 2015). I guess I am using the method `final()` wrongly, but I can't get a direct example from https://github.com/datejs/Datejs .

Comment: Is there any reason to use Datejs? It looks like it's really old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within DateJS there is an `moveToLastDayOfMonth` function.

**Example**

```
Date.july().moveToLastDayOfMonth()

or,

Date.today().set({year:2015,month:6}).moveToLastDayOfMonth()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used `DateJS`, but from a quick study, I guess this is what you'd want:

```
Date.today().set({year:2015,month:7,day:1}).add(-1).days()
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

There's a specific method to do that. First you have to set the date, obviously, and that can be done on an initialized Date object with `now()` or `today()`. I'd suggest today as that will zero out the time values:

```
Date.today().set({year:2015,month:6}).moveToLastDayOfMonth()
```

This will get you to the exact data you need.

Secondly, if you're using DateJS **PLEASE GOD** use the latest updated fork (disclaimer, I maintain it, I need to give it a little love but it *fixes so many issues* with the original library).

You can find that here: https://github.com/abritinthebay/datejs

It's also available as the npm datejs package and in bower. A simple `npm install datejs` will do if you use NodeJS.